# CLR crash only when run from a PowerShell job - how to diagnose

Tags: .net, windows, security, winapi, debugging

I've got a .NET program that **crashes inside the CLR JIT** with internal stack overflows and out-of-memory errors, **but *only* when run from inside a PowerShell job**.

I'm assuming that running it as a powershell job imposes some kinds of resource or **security limits** that cause .NET CLR to go nuts.

The most clear clue that I was able to get was that one of those errors once manifested itself as an exception from HRESULT, which HRESULT was ERROR_COMMITMENT_LIMIT (pagefile exhausted), though there was really plenty of room in the pagefile and in the RAM. Other times, these errors happened in completely arbitrary and innocent places of the program.

How can I diagnose what exactly is going wrong, **what limits are being violated**? Is there an API to get all restrictions that a process is subject to? Or is there a way to intercept or log a WinAPI call that fails because of a security or quota restriction? I'm quite ok with using even WinDbg for that, but I don't know how to use it for this task.

Comment: What user does the job run as?  Also, do you have any interesting errors in the event log?  Try attaching the debugger, with enough symbols loaded, perhaps you can get a good call stack from the exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryException / ERROR_COMMITMENT_LIMIT with a LOT of free memory in the system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419524/outofmemoryexception-error-commitment-limit-with-a-lot-of-free-memory-in-the-sy)

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that PowerShell is directly at fault here.  It imposes no security or CLR modifications which are passed down to child processes that it creates.

The one item PowerShell will definitely pass down to the child process is environment variables.  It's very possible that PowerShell is passing down a different environment variable than say CMD which is affecting the CLR or your Program and causing it to crash.  I would start up a CMD and PowerShell session and diff their environment variables to rule this out as a cause.

In particular I would pay attention to the `%PATH%` variable.

Comment: Well - I believe it is not true that PowerShell imposes no security limits. IIRC, e.g. remote Powershell jobs by default have reduced network permissions. However it's a good idea to look at environment variables.

Comment: @jkff I'm meaning more a default PowerShell environment. If the OP is using a custom PS environment I'd hope they'd comment on it :).  I wasn't aware of network jobs though having reduced permissions.